# JSON parsing from a website randomly errors with 500

Tags: .net, json, vb.net, parsing, post

I created an application that logs in to an external website (out of my control) to the monitor-service that we bought. Website is basically a Web API with GUI for vendor-like machines.

Due some stuff i wanted to make SMTP alerts if something went wrong since our provider hasn't created such functionality yet.

My code works with `HttpWebRequest` and my application is opening the website, signing in, redirecting with success. But when I call POST, it gives me 500 HTTP error mostly. Error is completely random because sometimes everything can succeed and work completely fine, and just in few minutes not work.

Some of my code:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
Dim request As HttpWebRequest = CType(HttpWebRequest.Create("https://website.com"), HttpWebRequest)
Dim cookieContainer = New CookieContainer()
    request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer
    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0 WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36"
    request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
    request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate Or DecompressionMethods.GZip
    request.Host = "xxx"
    request.Headers.Add("DNT", "1")

    Dim Fullhtmlcode As String

    Using response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        Using sr As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
            Fullhtmlcode = sr.ReadToEnd
        End Using
    End Using

    Dim SearchingString As String = "somestring"
    Dim SearchingStringIndexINt As Integer = Fullhtmlcode.IndexOf(SearchingString)
    Dim length As Integer = SearchingString.Length
    Dim TokenArr() As Char = Fullhtmlcode.ToCharArray(SearchingStringIndexINt + length, 40)
    Dim TokenString As String = New String(TokenArr)

    request = TryCast(WebRequest.Create("https://website.com"), HttpWebRequest)
    request.KeepAlive = True
    request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer
    request.Headers.Add("DNT", "1")
    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0 WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36"
    request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
    request.Method = "POST"
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    request.KeepAlive = True
    request.AllowAutoRedirect = True
    request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate Or DecompressionMethods.GZip

    Dim Data As String = ("_token=" + TokenString + "&login=login&password=password")
    Dim bytes As Byte() = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Data)
    request.ContentLength = bytes.Length

    'login in
    Using dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
        dataStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
        dataStream.Close()
    End Using

    Using response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
            'Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd())
        End Using
    End Using

    'get json data
    Try
        Dim requester As HttpWebRequest = CType(HttpWebRequest.Create("https://website.com/ajax/getMachines"), HttpWebRequest)


        requester.Method = "POST"
        requester.Host = "website.com"
        requester.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0 WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36"
        requester.Accept = "application/json, text/plain, */*"
        requester.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate Or DecompressionMethods.GZip
        requester.ContentType = "application/json;charset=utf-8"
        requester.KeepAlive = True
        requester.CookieContainer = cookieContainer
        requester.Referer = "https://website.com/"

        Dim Uri = New Uri("https://website.com/ajax/getMachines")
        'adding X-XSRF-TOKEN
        For Each coookie In cookieContainer.GetCookies(Uri)
            If coookie.ToString().Contains("XSRF-TOKEN") Then
                Dim CookieLenght As Integer = coookie.ToString().Length
                Dim c() As Char = coookie.ToString().ToCharArray(11, CookieLenght - 11)
                Dim d As String = New String(c)
                requester.Headers.Add("X-XSRF-TOKEN", c)
                requester.Headers.Add("DNT", "1")
            End If
        Next

        Data = "json data"
        requester.ContentLength = Data.Length
        bytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Data)
        requester.ContentLength = bytes.Length

        Using dataStream As Stream = requester.GetRequestStream() 'calling json 
            dataStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
            dataStream.Close()
        End Using

        Using responser As WebResponse = requester.GetResponse()   'random error 500
            Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(responser.GetResponseStream())
                Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd())
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

Comment: If you catch the `WebException` that is generated, and the take a look at the `Response` object in it, it may provide additional information as to what the problem is.  Explicitly, the `ResponseStream` will contain the response output by the server which sometimes can contain error information

Comment: @Martin does "protocol error" means something in `WebException.status`? I also looked inside `responser` but I couldn't find anything usefull other than saying it's internal server error.